# Store file/attachment in draft using Gmail?

Tags: android, android-intent

like :

**we can send an email with an attachment in android app by using `Intent`**

So :

**Is this possible to store attachment in draft using email through code ??**

Comment: You can send email using intent through gmail but AFAIK you can not save email as draft programmatically.

Answer (score 3):

> we can send an email with an attachment in android app by using Intent

No, you can *ask the user* to send an email with an attachment using an `Intent`. Whether the user actually follows through on that request is up to the user.

> Is this possible to store attachment in draft using email through code ??

No. Not all email clients even have the concept of "store attachment in draft".

Answer (score 2):

You can send email using intent through gmail but AFAIK you can not save email as draft programmatically. No email application's provide such functionality to save the email programmatically in draft.